# What is the regular expression to get the first 'id' from the response containing multiple id?

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

How to extract the ID of the first object from the response? I am getting the below response of the API.

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"description":"Test description 1", "Location": "test location 1"}, {"id":2,"description":"Test description 2", "Location": "test location 2"}, {"id":3,"description":"Test description 3", "Location": "test location 3"}]}
```

I want to extract the id= 1, from the above response. I have tried with `{"id":(.+?),` regular expression. But I am getting randomly any of the id. What is the regular expression to get the first id from the response?

Comment: Why would you use regex to parse json?

Comment: @ruohola, I am using regular expression extractor, that's why I am using regex. I want to pass the id to the next API request.

Comment: @ruohola, I have edited my question. Here is the actual format of the response I am getting. I have uploaded the question with json to easy to understand.

Comment: You should not use regex for this, period.

Comment: @ruohola, Then what should I use instead of Regex?

Comment: A proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead of Regular expression extractor for the JSON response.

To extract the first id from the response you mentioned, use JSON path expressions as : `.data[0].id`

Example Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Now, you can pass the variable `test` to your next API request as `${test}`

Answer (score 2):

To get what you **want** (bad idea):

Regex:

```
"id":(\d+),.*
```

Get the result with `\1`.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/nkKCAF/1).

---

To get what you **need**: use a proper json parser. Regexes are not suitable for handling complex stuff (also including HTML among many others).